# Jetty RewriteHandler and RewriteRegexRule

Tags: java, regex, jetty, mod-rewrite, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to rewrite a URL for a servlet. The URL gets rewritten correctly, but the context doesn't match after that. Any idea how to get this to work?

```
RewriteHandler rewriteHandler = new RewriteHandler();
rewriteHandler.setRewriteRequestURI(true);
rewriteHandler.setRewritePathInfo(true);
rewriteHandler.setOriginalPathAttribute("requestedPath");

RewriteRegexRule rewriteRegexRule = new RewriteRegexRule();
rewriteRegexRule.setRegex("/r/([^/]*).*");
rewriteRegexRule.setReplacement("/r?z=$1");
rewriteHandler.addRule(rewriteRegexRule);

ContextHandlerCollection contextHandlerCollection = new ContextHandlerCollection();
Context servletContext = new Context(contextHandlerCollection, "/");

servletContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new RedirectServlet()), "/r");
```

So basically `/r/asdf` gets rewritten to `/r?z=asdf`.

However, the rewritten `/r?z=asdf` is now not processed by the servlet.

Also, `/r?z=asdf` does work if called directly.

I've pasted the full code here: http://pastebin.com/Z1isNADg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I wanted `RedirectRegexRule` instead of `RewriteRegexRule`.